# android: Set time from time picker in dynamic edit text in table row

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, tablelayout, timepicker

I have a tablelayout with programmatically created table rows and a programmatically created **edit text** within each row. A table row is added by a click of a button which has the **edit text** named **'editTextTime'** within each row. The 'editTextTime' is clickable, so when you click on it a time picker dialog appears. After the time is selected from the time picker it appears in 'editTextTime'.

But here's the problem, when the time is selected it appears in another 'editTextTime' too at the same time, if two rows were selected. I need the time after selection only to be set as text in the selected 'editTextTime' of the current row it is inside and not to appear inside any other 'editTextTime' from another row. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (I suppose) is that you named all the EditTexts the same and the setTimeToEditText function is outside of the "programmatically creation code", so, you need to set the onClickListener for each one like this.

**UPDATE** I will post a simple example adding EditText programmatically

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    LinearLayout myLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

        final EditText myEditText = new EditText(MainActivity.this); // Pass it an Activity or Context
        //Stuff to make your edittext looks nice
        myEditText .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { //When you click on the            
                // Process to get Current Time
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, //same Activity Context like before
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                            int minute) {
                        myEditText.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute); //You set the time for the EditText created
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                tpd.show();

            }
        });
        myLayout.addView(myEditText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But 'mHour' and 'mMinute' are showing an error because they haven't been declared anywhere? Where do I declare them and what do I declare them as?

Comment: Declare where you are creating the timepicker...
Answer Updated

Comment: There are two problems and one of them is cause the time picker not run and the app to crash when I click on the field. Problem 1: The 'v' in v.setText... gets an error: 'The method setText(String) is undefined for the type View'. I added a cast like this: '((EditText) v).setText...' and there wasn't an error with it anymore but it is still not working.

Comment: Problem 2: The EditText originally had 'this' in it and so I added 'this' to the Time picker dialog replacing 'context' but that gave it an error. But when I changed it to context and changed the edit text 'this' to 'context' too the error disappeared but the app still crashes when I click on the field. So, not sure which it could be. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Btw, the error message I was getting for problem 2 when i had 'this' in the time picker dialog listener was: The constructor TimePickerDialog(new View.OnClickListener(){}, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){}, int, int, boolean) is undefined

Comment: ok, Problem 2: you can handle this changing 'this' or 'context' to 'YourApp.this' i'll change it in my answer as well. Problem 1: you can make it final. see the Updates

Comment: I figured it out now, it works fine!! The solution was having Activity.this in the time picker listener. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Just saw your comment and update, thank you for them. The cast in the v.setText... was fine, it was just the 'this' part that was causing the problem. but it works fine now.